# How to hide Login with OAuth 2.0 page with multiple clients

Tags: spring, security, oauth-2.0, boot

I have situation that I have 2 oauth 2.0 authorization servers with different redirect_uri.

I want to hide this page where I need to pick which server I want and make redirect automatically base on scope.

Is it possible? I won't to show this page to an external client, he should be redirected properly without asking.

Spring boot, Spring security, oauth2

Comment: Store a value in a session, indicating the requested scope?